# Parallel processing a mundane task

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am writing a small python script that essentially takes a list of urls each for a list of people and creates directories out of the url name. So for example, I have a file with 10 names and another 10 files with approximately 15-20 urls per person. The output has to be folders of names with subfolders for each link per person:

John Smith
   www.google.com
   www.yahoo.com

I am trying to experiment with multithreading with python to speed up this process as right now it is pretty slow for ~600 people with ~40 urls each. I want to split up the peoples into segments (say 25% in each segment) and have them be processed simultaneously. How can i accomplish this? A code snippet will be helpful!

Comment: Which version are you running?  This could be a great application for the [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio.html) additions in 3.4.  It would also help to see the critical sections of your code.

Comment: I am on 2.7. I am just unsure what paradigm i should be using. I mean is this a threading application or clustering approach? I dont really care if resources are shared or anything as I will just be segmenting an array of people names and each task will run only within the bounds given to it. (task1(array[0:50) task2(array[51:100]) Please advice

Comment: Can you distill the slow area down to a relatively small chunk of code?  It's hard to give general advice when it comes to performance questions.

Comment: Yea the slow part is essentially getting the urls (through a curl request to a server)

Comment: Ok, then I'd start trying to split the execution using a `multiprocessing.Pool` to run all of the URLs for a user.  If this doesn't give you the performance you're looking for, you could look at scaling the pool size up and down or dispatching individual (user, url) tuples rather than splitting by user alone.